# Unrecoverable Funds

Tags: recover-private-key, wallet-recovery

If I have sent funds from one wallet to another, but locked myself out of the wallet I sent them to due to the fact I do not remember my PIN and did not write down my pass phrase.  Is there any way to mine them or recover my funds?

Comment: Please specify which wallet and operating system you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right,
You sent bitcoin to another wallet, but forgot the pin and recovery key, effectively locking yourself out.

Nope. Your pin number would help you get into the wallet, and if you forgot it, you are supposed to have a recovery key. This recovery key is your last line of defence.

No way to recover them, unless you're using a 2-of-3 multisig wallet, where you can contact BitGo and then contact the external storage solution for your private key.

Usually all wallets say right to your face to back it up. I have no idea why you didn't.